# Localize js file with LazZiya Express Localization

Tags: lazziya.expresslocalization

I'm using LazZiya Express Localization to localize my project.
I have question:
Can I use LazZiya localization for js file (vuejs)?
Example:

```
const renderVueForm = () => {
    console.log('site js');
    let html = `<div localize-content>Oh my darling i love you so. You mean everything to me.</div>`;

    return html;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your localizable text in a hidden html div:

```html
<div id="my-localized-text" class="d-none" localize-content>
    Oh my darling i love you so. You mean everything to me.
</div>
```

Then in JS get the content of the localized div:

```js
const renderVueForm = () => {
    console.log('site js');
    let html = $("#my-localized-text").html();

    return html;
};
```